# C# Winforms - Owner-drawn listbox with multiple colors in the same line

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, listbox, controls

I found an article that does exactly what I need. It draws multiple colors on the same line on a text box. But the problem is that it was written in VB.NET and I'm writing my program in C#. Any good soul can convert this to C# if it is possible and if it isn't can you give me other options? Thanks.

This is the article: http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, they aren't using a Textbox in this article, they are using a Listbox but what follows is a conversion of the code from VB.Net to C# like you asked. It needs tidied up a bit but it does the job.

Just create a new Windows Form, place a Listbox called lstColor onto this form, change the `DrawMode` property to **OwnerDrawFixed** inside the properties window, then add event handlers for **DrawItem** and **MeasureItem** (you can add event handlers by clicking on the lightning bolt in the Properties window, and double clicking the whitespace beside these two words in the list).

In the **DrawItem** event handler, add the following:

```
private void lstColor_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var size = g.MeasureString(data[e.Index], oFont, 500, sf);
    var width = size.Width + 16;

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(data[e.Index], oFont, new SolidBrush(color[e.Index]), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(data[data.Length - 1 - e.Index], oFont, new SolidBrush(color[color.Length - 1 - e.Index]), width, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

In the **MeasureItem** event handler, add this:

```
private void lstColor_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    var size = g.MeasureString(data[e.Index], oFont, 500, sf);
    var height = size.Height;

    e.ItemHeight = Convert.ToInt32(height);
}
```

Add five private fields outside the scope of any methods but inside your **Form1** (or whatever you've called your form) class like so:

```
private string[] data;
private Color[] color;
private Font oFont;
private Graphics g;
private StringFormat sf;
```

Put the following three lines inside your **Form1_Load** event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oFont = new Font("Arial", 10);

    data = new string[] { "This is Red", "This is Blue", "This is Green", "This is Yellow", "This is Black", "This is Aqua", "This is Brown", "This is Cyan", "This is Gray", "This is Pink" };
    color = new Color[] {Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Yellow, Color.Black, Color.Aqua, Color.Brown, Color.Cyan, Color.Gray,Color.Pink};
    lstColor.DataSource = data;
    g = Graphics.FromHwnd(lstColor.Handle);
    sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
}
```

And you are all set.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

here is the conversion of what you posted Nicolas

if you need to change / get anything else working you will need to test it on your end..

Happy coding

```
private void  MeasureItemHandler(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(lstColor.Handle);
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    SizeF size = default(SizeF);
    float height = 0;
    Font oFont = new Font("Arial", 10);

    //measure the height of what you are about to draw
    //and let the listbox know this
    size = g.MeasureString(data(e.Index), oFont, 500, sf);
    height = size.Height + 5;
    e.ItemHeight = height;
}

private void  DrawItemHandler(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(lstColor.Handle);
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    SizeF size = default(SizeF);
    float width = 0;
    Font oFont = new Font("Arial", 10);


    //get the width of the string you are about to write
    //this info is needed so that we can offset the next 
    //string that will be drawn in a different color.
    size = g.MeasureString(data(e.Index), oFont, 500, sf);
    width = size.Width + 16;

    //prepare the list for drawing
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    //draw the first string in a certain color
    e.Graphics.DrawString(data(e.Index), oFont, new SolidBrush(color(e.Index)), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);

    //draw the second string in a different color
    e.Graphics.DrawString(data(data.Length - 1 - e.Index), oFont, new SolidBrush(color(color.Length - 1 - e.Index)), width, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://converter.telerik.com/  It converts code from VB.NET to C# and C# to VB.NET.  It wont work on complex code, but could prove useful to you.